rstp player Android Studio TV apk
I'm trying to learn about these issues and I need support.
I have a video camera and I want to take images from this camera. Video H264
I can access the image by typing the rtsp address in VLC player.
rtsp://admin:password123@192.168.1.52:554/Profile1/Media.smp
I'm trying to make an apk that will work on an android TV. I want to watch the image coming from rtsp address on the screen.
language : java
Build configuration language : Groovy DSL(build.gradle)
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.video.cam">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:show_buffering="when_playing"
        app:resize_mode="fit" />
</FrameLayout>

MainActivity.java
package com.video.cam;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.OptIn;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem;
import androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.rtsp.RtspMediaSource;
import androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PlayerView playerView;
    private ExoPlayer player;

    @OptIn(markerClass = UnstableApi.class)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

        player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        playerView.setPlayer(player);

        String videoUrl = "rtsp://admin:password123@192.168.1.52:554/Profile1/Media.smp";

        MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(videoUrl).build();

        RtspMediaSource.Factory mediaSourceFactory = new RtspMediaSource.Factory();
        mediaSourceFactory.setForceUseRtpTcp(true);

        RtspMediaSource mediaSource = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(mediaItem);

        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
        player.prepare();
        player.play();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
        }
    }
}

build.gradle(Project)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

build.gradle(app)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    namespace 'com.video.cam'
    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.video.cam"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-rtsp:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.3.1'
}

When I try to compile the project I get the following error.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Can you please help me with this work?

Provide the full error and command line.
